# Ambiguity, PCFG grammar

Tags: computational-linguistics, syntax-trees, ambiguity

I know that the sentence "time flies like an arrow" could have lots of meaning and there is an ambiguity but I draw a tree and I got confused that which meaning is more suitable for this tree.

S→ NP VP

NP→ NN NN

VP→ V NP

NP→ Det NN

NN→ time, flies, arrow

det→ an

v→ like

meaning 1)there exists a particular arrow x such that every time flies (a kind of insect) likes x.( many flies one arrow)
meaning 2) for every every "time flies"(a kind of insect)y, there is an arrow x such that y likes x (many flies , one arrow per fly)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 'time flies' as you would mean 'fruit flies', then wouldn't 'time flies' have to be one NN, or 'time' to be a modifier? With your current phrase structure rules or lexicon you do not allow this interpretation. You'll have to add rules that either license a construction allowing 'time' to act as a modifier of 'flies', or change the lexicon.

Comment: Couldn't we say that Time is the name of the flies, then we need separate NN for that?

Comment: would that not indicate that the two words are somewhat separate, rather than depending on each other's meaning? I suppose this raises the question, is Charles Dickens 1 NN or 2 NN? I would certainly say it is one - only one entity being described.

Comment: Why is the leaf node called 'NN' instead of 'n'?

Comment: I think it's just a convention in some NLP circles: I believe NLTK uses NN to tag a noun. 

On the other hand, some NLP classes use NN for 'nominal'. This choice is argued by Halliday and functional grammar, although some may argue that a nominal group is/is too similar to a noun phrase. 


 Finally, in my natural language syntax classes we labelled our trees with just N for any noun.